# Nginx rewtire question mark

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, special-characters

I use Windows 7 for developing web sites. Now I have a problem on rewrite an url. Try to change a question mark to an underscore, but nothings seems to work.

```
location /site/ {
        rewrite "^skript.php([?]{1})(.*)$" skript.php_$2;
}
```

Url should be "skript.php_$args.

Solution needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` is the delimiter for the *query string*. The `rewrite` and `location` directives use a normalised URI which already has the query string removed and placed into `$args`.

There are a number of ways to append `_$args` to the URI, depending on what you are trying to achieve. For example:

```
location = /foo.php {
    rewrite ^ $uri_$args?;
}
```

Or:

```
location = /foo.php {
    return 301 $uri_$args;
}
```

Or:

```
rewrite ^/foo.php$ $uri_$args?;
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.